# JavaScript validate phone number and extension starts with *

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate phone number and extension.

1. Phone number would be 10 digits long (only numeric).
2. Extension will start with *55 and max 6 digits.

I placed a validation for phone number using below RegEx.

```
var regExOther = /^[0-9*]+$/;
if(!regExOther.test(phone)) //phone may have 9898123456 or *552341
{
    //my error flag
}
```

Current solution only works for Digits and not for extension (*55....).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are extensions optional ?

Comment: You can use this regex `/^\d{10}(?:\*55\d{0,4})?$/`

Comment: How long can the extension be? Is it added to 10 digit numbers or separate? Please add some test cases.

Comment: @Toto, a user can either able to add 10 digit phone number OR an extension starting with `*55` with max 6 digits (which includes 55).

Comment: Yes @marvel308, an extension is option. User can enter either an extension or phone number.

Comment: So, is my answer giving what you want?

Comment: I wrote comment under your answer, @Toto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to match 10 digit telephone number OR extensions that begin with `*55` followed by 0 upto 4 digits.

```js
var test = [
    '1234567890',
    '12345678901',
    'abc',
    '*55',
    '*551234',
    '*5512345',
    '*45123',
    '551234',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^(?:\d{10}|\*55\d{0,4})$/.test(a);
}));
```

A simple function should be:

```js
function validPhone(a) {
    return /^(?:\d{10}|\*55\d{0,4})$/.test(a);
}
console.log(validPhone('1234567890'));
```

Comment: I tested it using "Run code snippet" and yes it returns correct answers. Can you also suggest single value / function argument along with above solution?

Comment: console.log(/^(?:\d{10}|\*55\d{0,4})$/.test('1234567890'));

Comment: Yes @Toto, it'd done. Thank you very much. Your answer is perfect match for my question. :) (y)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```js
function match(str){
    return str.match(/(?:^\*55\d{6}$)|^\d{10}$/);
}


console.log(match('1234567890'));
console.log(match('*551234567890'));
console.log(match('*55123456'));
console.log(match('1234567'));
```

In the regex

**(?:*55)** matches if the string starts with an extension 
**\d{10}** matches the case that it should have 10 digits